# Extracting text from HTML table

Tags: vba, web-scraping, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to extract various elements from this page:

http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?searchText=4CE0460D0G

I want to start with `ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_lblSerialNumber`.

Surely there must be an easy solution to extract elements you want from the HTML page if you know the ID? I thought something like `getElementsByName` or `getElementById` or even `getElementsByTagName` would work but I cannot get it to extract what I want, try as I might!

This doesn't work:

```
 Function GetHPModelName()

     Dim ie As Object
        Dim Oelement As Object
        Dim Ohtml As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Dim lrow As Integer

        With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?searchText=" & Worksheets("HP_Lookup").Range("A2").Value, False
        .send
        Ohtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        End With


    FetchHPInfo "ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_lblSerialNumber", "A", Oelement, Ohtml 
End Function
```

Calling

```
Public Function FetchHPInfo(tablename As String, thiscolumn As String, Oelement As Object, Ohtml As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
lrow = 1
For Each Oelement In Ohtml.getElementsById(tablename)
    Worksheets("HP_main").Range(thiscolumn & lrow).Value = Oelement.innerText
    lrow = lrow + 1
    Next Oelement
    Worksheets("HP_main").Columns(thiscolumn).cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
    Worksheets("HP_main").Columns(thiscolumn).AutoFit
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById()` should be all you need, since the node has an ID attribute. You may be having an issue because you're trying to assign `responseText` to the document body but the document doesn't have a `<body>` node yet. Just use `write()` to write the entire response into the empty document. Here's an example I threw together that returns the proper value:

```
Dim objHttp
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objHttp.Open "GET", "http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?searchText=4CE0460D0G", False
objHttp.Send

Dim doc
Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
doc.write objHttp.responseText

MsgBox doc.getElementById("ctl00_BodyContentPlaceHolder_lblSerialNumber").innerText
```

Output:

```
4CE0460D0G
```